# randomly generate either -1 or 1

Tags: r, random-generation

How do I generate values either -1 or 1 in R ?

`sample(0:1,10,replace=T)` produces random 10 samples of either 1 or 0.

If I modify this code to `sample(-1:1,10,replace=T)` I see three different values -1 or 0 or 1. I am just interested in -1 or 1.

Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not saying that there's not a more direct or better way to do this.  But note that if x is 0 or 1, then 2 * x - 1 maps 0 into -1 and 1 into 1.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone thanks Mark I can use various transformation. I am looking for a function that will avoid requiring extra lines of codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sampling from the range -1:1, sample from the list -1, 1.

Comment: Exactly. `-1:1` produces the *sequence* `-1,0,1`. Instead use `sample(c(-1,1),10,replace=T)`